# installing react-native-firebase/auth causes [Error: [firestore/unknown] UNAUTHENTICATED]

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am using react-native-firebase to manage my connection with firebase, I have so far used the `react-native-firebase/firestore` and `react-native-firebase/database` and now I want to add authentication to the mix when I install `react-native-firebase/auth` without editing any of my current code or firebase rules any time I try communicating with firestore (read/write)  I get the error `[Error: [firestore/unknown] UNAUTHENTICATED]`

I have tried to create an `authContext`  and sign in users anonymously.

and I have made sure that all the firebase libraries are on the latest version `(18.7.3)`

```
    "node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app": {
      "version": "18.7.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-native-firebase/app/-/app-18.7.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-KlUuLSCYrBMHXE2Evye1fzrqunUjFEPihxcpzuUyJ5yQyAuCNws7VGdEPIaXoKz1esof0uv8wMSxD+G6W+Vi8Q==",
      "dependencies": {
        "opencollective-postinstall": "^2.0.3",
        "superstruct": "^0.6.2"
      },
      "peerDependencies": {
        "expo": ">=47.0.0",
        "react": "*",
        "react-native": "*"
      },
      "peerDependenciesMeta": {
        "expo": {
          "optional": true
        }
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@react-native-firebase/database": {
      "version": "18.7.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-native-firebase/database/-/database-18.7.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-4fivWVRZHZatypPNudP8p0dk1Up7VGrSZdTnRYuYa5V0RnGj2BzFJUtU4cyG8bdCz8vov56TJuEeayRA9ArAkA==",
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "18.7.3"
      }
    },
    "node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore": {
      "version": "18.7.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@react-native-firebase/firestore/-/firestore-18.7.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-ts5clqDnpXw2nnX7W9H9+AZbh0jyXNIjnhHfTnMpstpCDQ3DCld/d8Ta2n/jzLUGRhtkCd0iALXmvVQBNNOTSQ==",
      "peerDependencies": {
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "18.7.3"
      }
    },
```